# Computer only runs memtest, cannot find files in grub

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I rebooted my computer when I left work one day, and, when I came back, it was running memtest.  It had been running memtest for just short of two days.

I've entered the grub menu.

```
grub> ls -l
Device proc: Filesystem type procfs - Sector size 512B - Total size 0KiB
Device hd0: No known filesystem detected - sector size 512B
  Partition hd0,msdos5: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 250880KiB - Total size 243947520
  Partition hd0,msdos1: Filesystem type ext* - UUID cf8c5205-b560-4cb1-9417-dcf29a8b1f98 - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 248832KiB
Device fd0: Filesystem cannot be accessed
```

I can only access one partition, `hd0,msdos1`, though the `hd0,msdos5` looks a whole lot like my main partition.  I'm guessing that figuring out how to access `hd0,msdos5` is the key to solving this.

This is what `hd0,msdos1` looks like

```
grub> set root=(hd0,msdos1)
grub> ls /
lost+found/ grub/ memtest86+.bin memtest86+.elf memtest86+_multiboot.bin System.map-3.13.0-36-generic
```

This problem was most likely caused when I tried to clean up my `/boot` directory, which had too many kernels in it and I couldn't install anything.  I thought running `sudo apt-get update` would make `apt-get` fix anything that I accidentally deleted, but I obviously was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried boot-repair?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  In the future you can clean up extraneous kernels with Ubuntu Tweak http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise running Boot repair as Organic Marble suggested.

Make a live USB/CD of Ubuntu, and boot your PC in that.

Then open a terminal and type the following, pressing enter after each line

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then try the recommended repair option. Once that is complete, reboot your PC back into your hard drive and GRUB should work again!